# Grafana : Average Calculation + Dynamic Threshold

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am new to Grafana World. I needed to clear two things with you guys:

1) Is there anyway to dynamically change threshold within a time range?

2) How does Grafana calculate Average? Is there a way to calculate average by dividing total count by a constant variable using lucene?

I am using Elasticsearch as Data source.

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like this has been implemented yet.

You can follow the open issues on the Grafana repo

- https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/159
- https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/922

Comment: These issues seem to never be closes/implemented

Answer (score 0):

Maybe querying the value as Templating and call it on the threshold options?
For example with MySQL, having $THRESH_MIN_GRAPH_LOGINS as SELECT LEAST(1, MIN(value) - 5) AS __value FROM logins WHERE $__timeFilter(date), then on edit graph, write the variable name; or as proposed, being able to write this query inside of the threshold tab.

Comment: That doesn't work. Thresholds need to be fixed values for now. Here: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/159 and https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/922

Answer (score 0):

As per github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/159 you can do this since Grafana 8.1 by using the transformation "Config from query results" [https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transformations/config-from-query/lt"](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transformations/config-from-query/lt%22)